# Plotly multiple axes colors merge

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Im trying to plot the different stats of two football players mirrored across. Id like the better stat to have a green color and the worse stat red. Only problem is In my color scale one color will be red and one will be green which merges both. Does anyone know a solution or a better way to plot this kind of graph?

```
data =[['Messi', 88]]
   data2 = [['Ronaldo', -88]]

   df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Player', 'Dribbling'])
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Player', 'Dribbling'])

   fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

   fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            orientation='h',
            name=df['Player'],
            x=df['Dribbling'],
            marker_color=((df.Dribbling >= df2.Dribbling)).astype('int'),
            marker_colorscale=[[0, 'red'], [1, 'green']],
            ),secondary_y=False)
            

   fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            orientation='h',
            name=df2['Player'],
            x=df2['Dribbling'],
            marker_color=((df.Dribbling >= df2.Dribbling)).astype('int'),
            marker_colorscale=[[0, 'red'], [1, 'green']],
            ),secondary_y=True)

   fig.update_layout(
      barmode="group"
   )
   fig.update_xaxes(range=[-100, 100])
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure the colors are actually combining. If you plot only one of the bars, it's the same color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method could be simplified a bit. It doesn't seem like a secondary y-axis is needed, just a categorical one for the different players. I also think that the way you have set up your colors, brown is the actual color - if you only plot one bar, it's still that brown color.

An easier way to achieve what you want is to combine both players' information in one DataFrame, then create a column called `"Color"` where the minimum score is mapped to `"red"` and the maximum score is mapped to `"green"`, then loop through the rows of your DataFrame and add a horizontal bar as a trace for each loop iteration.

This method has the advantage of being generalizable: if you want to plot the stats of other football players and have their bars be another color, you can modify the DataFrame and the plotting code will still work.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame([['Messi', 88],['Ronaldo', -88]], columns=['Player', 'Dribbling'])
df["Color"] = ['red' if x==min(df.Dribbling) else "green" if x==max(df.Dribbling) else np.nan for x in df.Dribbling]

fig = go.Figure()
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        orientation='h',
        name=row.Player,
        x=[row.Dribbling],
        y=[row.Player],
        marker_color=row.Color,
    ))
        
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The secondary axis isnt really needed indeed but i'd like it to look that way on my site. But i'll just use two graphs.